# Git - how to merge "softly"?

Tags: git, git-merge

I came up with the "softly" expression because you can **almost** have the wanted the result with the following commands:

```
git merge <branch>
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Doing so will keep all final changes from merge in memory, and you just have to commit them. But the problem is that when committing, git doesn't consider this as a merge commit anymore.

Another way to almost get the same result is merging with conflicts. Once you resolve all your conflicts and you commit, git knows it's a merge commit.

Comment: what exactly is the goal you try to achieve?

Comment: To be able to compare and edit all changes before committing the merge. Like git allows to when merging a branch with conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you're searching for

```
git merge --no-commit <someBranch>
```

([doc here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-commit))

It's a way to **assert that it's a conflict** and you want git to treat this merge as such.

You start the merge, have a chance to inspect and modify whatever you need, then when you're fine with it and decide to commit it's still a commit merge, with (at least) two parents.

*(Warning : `-n` is **not** a shortcut for this, but rather for `--no-stat`)*

Comment: Thanks! The command seems to be clearly what I asked for. But [it seems it doesn't do the job](https://i.giphy.com/media/loMfDXgPi0XQr1SOxU/source.gif). It commits right away.

Comment: My bad! The shortcut `-n` is in fact for `--no-stat`... sorry for the inconvenience. To go back before the merge, (I've the feeling you don't need me for this but just in case I'm wrong) you'll have to reset (`git reset --hard HEAD^`) and redo the merge with `--no-commit` this time.)

Comment: Perfect!
I should have tested the `--no-commit`.
Don't worry for the reset lol, and thanks.